# Pause SSH Session

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I have long running processes that I just kick off. I create ssh and long-in into ssh session and create multiple screens and run all the programs and detached using (ctr + A + D). But when i resume (screen + r) and try to see my outputs the server have become slow. All process are working but no one of them is finished yet. And I finally decided to pause some of the screens and run few of them in order to finish the programs running as fast as possible.

I need help if it is possible to pause some of the running processes.

Comment: Ask here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `nohup` is a popular way to ignore the `SIGHUP` your process will get when the remote terminal closes.  `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT` can be used to pause/resume activity on those processes.

Comment: You can try CTRL+Z. This will pause the foreground process and return to the bash prompt. See the list of running process with `jobs` and resume with `fg`. If the process is CPU intensive does not make sense running more instances than the number of CPUs in the system, same goes for other resources like memory and I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a signal to the processes to stop (pause) them:

```
kill -SIGSTOP <PID>
```

to continue the process at a later time do:

```
kill -SIGCONT <PID>
```

from the signal man page (man 7 signal):

```
   SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped
   SIGSTOP   17,19,23    Stop    Stop process
```

This of course will only work if the programs that you're running are handling these signals correctly.
The other way is to hit CTRL-Z on the shell where you have started the processes. That will stop them. With 'bg' you can start them again in the background or you can use 'fg' to start them again in the foreground.

Hope that helps.